# Utilizador e senha aparecem no console após o POST

Tags: angularjs, segurança

O código abaixo faz um POST dos dados inseridos pelo utilizador no login.

```
$http.post('api/v1/login', object).then(function (results) {
    return results.data;
});
```

Repare que passo como parâmetro um objecto que contém os dados inseridos no login:

```
//exemplo de um objecto após preencher os campos senha/login
{"customer":{"email":"filipe@teste.com","password":"123456"}}
```

O problema é que ao fazer o debug no console do Firefox, consigo ver o e-mail e a senha digitada, veja:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Isso não levanta problemas de segurança?***

Como a aplicação é feita com AngularJS, o refresh da página não existe, se deixar a console aberta, quem utilizar a aplicação naquele computador terá os dados expostos caso faça apenas "logout" e mantenha o browser aberto.

Comment: Eu estava pesquisando sobre algo relativo e na verdade, a única segurança é a da transmissão (criptografia) fisicamente o usuário tem de ter acesso a todos os seus dados. Se ele deixar o computador desprotegido é falha física de segurança, e não de software

Comment: @Caputo a única maneira de resolver isso é forçar um refresh após o login, pelo menos já limpava o console, porém acho que perderia um pouco a lógica, uma vez que umas das premissas do AngularJS é evitar refresh a página.

Comment: É que na verdade a visão é que esta informação ficar "visivel" não é uma falha de segurança (segundo alguns conceitos que eu havia pesquisado algum tempo atrás)

Comment: Já que estão usando JS, o ideal seria enviar um hash da senha com um _salt_ de preferencia dado pelo servidor, e não a própria senha. (1) o servidor fornece o salt na página (2) o user preenche os dados e clica em enviar (3) a pagina faz um hash da senha com o salt e devolve no JSON (4) o servidor compara o retorno, "salgando" a senha armazenada com o mesmo salt enviado, e vê se batem. **Isso não é solução completa, mas já melhora um pouco a situação.**

Comment: @FilipeMoraes Refresh após login, realmente é uma inconveniência, mas acho imprescindível fazer um refresh **após o logout**: não só para limpar o console, mas para limpar quaisquer dados potencialmente confidenciais ainda presentes na memória do browser. Quanto a evitar da senha aparecer no console, talvez [um protocolo como o SRP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51875/215) ajude a proteger a senha original mesmo que alguém tenha acesso ao *browser* enquanto o usuário ainda está logado (aquela sessão já está comprometida, é claro, mas sessões futuras, não necessariamente...).

Answer (score 2):

Quando você faz um post, essas variáveis não ficam visíveis apenas na consola. A requisição que o navegador faz passa por dúzias de máquinas até chegar ao servidor. Todas as máquinas podem ler a requisição.

Se você logar nesse sistema a partir de uma rede, o administrador da rede pode ver o conteúdo completo do post através dos logs de acesso. E pode ver seus acessos em tempo real, com ferramentas como o *Fiddler2* ou o *Wireshark*.

O ideal é você forçar o utilizador a só acessar a página de login com o protocolo ***https***, a exemplo do que sites como o GMail fazem. Quando você utiliza ***https***, os dados do post são encriptados e não podem ser facilmente lidos por terceiros ao longo do caminho entre o navegador e o servidor. Não é 100% seguro, mas para a maioria dos casos é 99,999% seguro.

Com ***https*** ainda será possível ver as credenciais na consola do navegador. Mas como o Caputo falou, se o utilizador deixa o computador desprotegido, a falha de segurança é o utilizador e não o sistema.