# Como gerar um hash no client-side?

Tags: segurança, criptografia, hash

Estou pesquisando formas de criar um sistema de login com uma criptografia segura e que não pese para o servidor. 
Tomando como exemplo [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2405/5818) estou a pesquisar uma forma de fazer a criptografia do lado do cliente, enviando assim a senha já criptografada para o php, reduzindo assim a nescessidade de processamento. Minha intenção é usar `'cost'=> 12` ou maior para o BCrypt, só vai depender do desempenho no client-side em maquinas populares.

Porém estou aberto a outras possibilidades de criptgrafia que sejam possiveis do lado do cliente.

> Como foi citado pelo @Bacco em sua resposta:
>
> "Como o hashing é propositalmente "caro", faria sentido numa arquitetura cliente-servidor usar a CPU do cliente. Afinal, quando 100 clientes conectam a um servidor só, coletivamente eles tem muito mais poder de processamento."

Comment: Talvez seja mais vantagem usar SSL (HTTPS) do que implementar tudo isso do lado do cliente. Enviar o hash para o servidor vai ser basicamente a mesma coisa de enviar a senha. Se alguém interceptar este hash, tudo que ele precisa fazer é reenviar o hash para se autenticar.

Comment: @AndréRibeiro Se entendi bem sua colocação, acho que você está enganado, pois a verificação da senha tem como base a senha original, digitada pelo usuário. O que o Rodrigo quer, acredito eu, seria apenas gerar o hash ao cadastrar a senha. Mas posso estar errado, pois não foi especificado se é para o login ou o cadastro...

Comment: O @AndréRibeiro está certo, não importa se uma credencial de acesso é uma "senha", "chave", "hash" ou qualquer outra coisa - se apresentar aquilo pro servidor te autentica, então basta o atacante se apossar daquilo para ganhar acesso a sua conta. A defesa (i.e. o hash lento) tem então que ser aplicada naquilo, de modo a manter a credencial original fora do BD.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Você precisa de algo como o [Secure Remote Password protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol) (SRP). Como apontado por Earendul e André Ribeiro, simplesmente mover o hash do servidor pro cliente anula todos os benefícios de segurança - pois um atacante que obtiver uma cópia do BD pode simplesmente usar o hash armazenado para fazer login imediatamente como qualquer usuário (já que a **credencial de acesso** passa a ser o hash, e não a senha original). É preciso um protocolo cujas características de segurança se mantenham mesmo com o hash feito no lado cliente.

E esse protocolo é o SRP. O protocolo original possui uma fraqueza (fraqueza essa que se mantém presente na implementação padrão do SRP via SSL/TLS), que é o uso de um simples SHA-256 como função de hash, em vez de uma função lenta como o BCrypt. De modo que você teria de implementar você mesmo na camada de aplicação e/ou obter uma implementação segura da mesma forma.

Ele é um pouquinho mais complicado que a maioria dos protocolos - pois envolve diversas mensagens indo e vindo entre o cliente e o servidor. Há também alguns parâmetros a serem estabelecidos, consulte a referência indicada para mais detalhes.

Para registrar um novo usuário:

1. O cliente, cuja senha é `p`, escolhe um sal aleatório `s` e calcula o hash `x = H(s, p)`; calcula também `v = g^x`, onde `g` é um parâmetro comum entre o servidor e os clientes.
2. O servidor armazena `v` e `s` associado ao *username* desse cliente. `x` é descartado - de modo que mesmo se um atacante copiar o BD, ele não vai saber o resultado do hash.

Para um usuário existente fazer login:

1. O cliente escolhe uma chave secreta `a` aleatória (e efêmera) e envia `A = g^a` ao servidor (mais o seu *username*);
2. O servidor também escolhe um chave efêmera `b`, calcula `B = kv + g^b` (`k` é um parâmetro calculado independentemente por ambas as partes) e envia `B` e `s` pro cliente;
3. Ambos calculam `u = H(A, B)`;
4. O cliente calcula `Sc = (B-kg^x)^(a + ux)` e `K = H(Sc)`, fazendo uso de novo da sua senha `p` para obter `x`;
5. O servidor calcula `Ss = (Av^u)^b` e `K = H(Ss)`.

Agora tanto o cliente quanto o servidor possuem uma chave secreta e compartilhada (e efêmera), derivada em parte da senha do usuário. Resta somente cada um deles provar ao outro que chegaram ao mesmo resultado:

1. O cliente envia ao servidor `M1 = H(H(N) xor H(g) | H(I) | s | A | B | K)`, e o servidor verifica usando seu valor de `K`. `|` significa a concatenação de strings. `N` é outro parâmetro comum entre cliente e servidor, e `I` é simplesmente o *username*.
2. O servidor envia ao cliente `M2 = H(A | M1 | K)`, e o cliente verifica usando seu valor de `K`.

<sub>[Fonte: Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol#Protocol)</sub>

Esse é o protocolo original, que usa SHA-256 como hash. Como você pode observar, ele é usado diversas vezes durante o protocolo, de modo que é inviável substituí-lo por um hash lento em todos os seus usos - quando tudo o que você quer é proteger a senha. Uma opção preferível - como [apontada por Tom Leek](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/73237/6939) no security.SE - é manter o protocolo idêntico, só aplicar `p = BCrypt(s, p)` na senha antes de usá-la (pode-se usar o mesmo sal `s`, mas se viável é preferível usar um sal `s2` - se sua implementação der suporte é claro). Assim você ganha a proteção do hash sem aumentar a carga no servidor.

Um atacante que ganhe acesso ao BD somente verá `s` e `v = g^x`, de modo que ele teria que computar `x` para poder fazer login no servidor ("simulando" o protocolo *offline*). E como para chegar em `x` ele teria de refazer o *hash* lento, a proteção do mesmo está assegurada.

Comment: @RodrigoBorth Então, o protocolo inteiro usa um hash rápido (e portanto barato), somente a senha é reforçada pelo hash lento. E esse reforço é feito no lado cliente somente, o servidor só enxerga um parâmetro derivado da senha (o `v`) - que por si só não pode ser usado para recuperar a senha original, não sem refazer o hash. Em outras palavras, o conhecimento de `v` não ajuda o atacante a fazer login, ele precisa de fato de `x`. Como `x` não está armazenado em lugar algum, o único jeito de obtê-lo é refazendo o hash de `p`, daí a proteção conferida a ele mesmo no lado cliente.

Comment: Infelizmente, não... Pro lado cliente, [essa biblioteca](https://code.google.com/p/srp-js/) por exemplo deve servir, mas seria necessário implementar o lado servidor na sua linguagem de escolha. Um exemplo de servidor é dado, pro Django, mas adaptar isso para outras plataformas pode ser um pouco complicado, sim. Você precisa mesmo disso? Tem um sistema em que o número de usuários fazendo login simultaneamente está pesando no servidor? Eu gosto muito da ideia, mas nunca cheguei a usar na prática, por pura falta de necessidade mesmo...

Comment: Veja também [TLS-SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS-SRP), a implementação do SRP direto na camada de transporte. Não sei quais browsers dão suporte a ele, mas o OpenSSL 1.0.1 ou superior já dá. O único problema é adaptá-lo para fazer um hash forte no lado cliente, não sei em que pé as coisas estão, mas essa é uma preocupação geral, creio que muito em breve isso será levado em conta pelos implementadores, sem que tenhamos que fazer nada disso nós mesmos.

Comment: Queria ver ele chegar no setor de segurança de uma empresa de T.I de médio porte pra cima e dizer que vai colocar a criptografia do lado do cliente e ainda por cima, fora do https. Necessidade de reinventar a roda quando SSL já resolve o problema e ainda te dá tempo para você focar no que realmente interessa, desenvolvimento da aplicação. Essa  pergunta me parece com uma que vi no GUJ que o usuário falou que queria fazer um sistema onde cada usuário cadastrado no sistema teria uma tabela própia no sistema ao invez de usar uma tabela de usuários.

Comment: @wryel SSL trata-se do **tranporte** da senha, enquanto *hashing* trata do **armazenamento**. Além disso, as senhas em si são dados dignos de proteção, pois as pessoas rotineiramente (e indevidamente) reusam senhas ou variantes da mesma em vários lugares distintos. Pega muito mal pra uma empresa ter as senhas dos seus clientes roubadas, e isso acontece com empresas de qualquer tamanho. Se mover a criptografia pro lado cliente permite reforçar a segurança das senhas num nível bem maior que o que é possível no lado servidor, então é algo bastante desejável sim, desde que feito direito é claro.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, sua explicação responde a pergunta dele, mas, deixando em aberto da a possibilidade de outras respostas. Não vejo SSL como transporte de senha, e sim como canal seguro. Se pensarmos em outras possibilidade, talvez esse método ainda estaria vulnerável a MITM. Isso é um assunto bem longo e sempre haverá prós & contras.

Comment: @wryel Concordo, quando disse "transporte de senha" quis dizer transporte de dados em geral, inclusive mas não limitado a senhas - ou seja, canal seguro. Quanto a MitM, esse protocolo foi projetado de modo a ser resistente contra esse tipo de ataque - a menos que o atacante estivesse presente *na conexão inicial* (i.e. quando o usuário cria sua conta), ele não poderia executar um MitM nas conexões subsequentes, ou o protocolo falharia. De todo modo, sendo SRP algo novo e relativamente pouco usado, é bom sim ser cauteloso.

Comment: Referência: ["How does SRP prevent man-in-middle attacks?"](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/30998/6939)

Comment: @RodrigoBorth Talvez seja necessário um moderador ajudar nisso, pois não sei quais comentários são construtivos ou não (vejo a maioria deles como pertinentes ao assunto). Agora estou meio sem tempo, mas depois posso mover o que eu considero relevante pra resposta em si e apagar dos comentários. P.S. vou remover este comentário em breve.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar o [bcryptjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs).

```
var bcrypt = dcodeIO.bcrypt;
var hash = bcrypt.hashSync('password', 12);
```

Vale a pena realizar alguns testes de performance para verificar se um cost de 12 não ficará muito lento para máquinas mais simples. A própria wiki do bcryptjs possui um [benchmark](https://github.com/dcodeIO/bcrypt.js/wiki/Benchmark), mas vale lembrar que o teste foi realizado em um Intel Core i7-2600K.

Answer (score 3):

Codificando a senha no lado cliente e enviando pro servidor não irá lhe dar muito mais segurança. Se um intruso capturar essa senha codificada ele poderá usar exatamente essa senha futuramente, e o servidor não terá como saber se foi você ou não que está enviando essa senha codificada. Esse ataque é também conhecido como [Replay Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack). Claro que já é melhor que enviar a senha pura.

Para resolver esse problema pode usar o [Nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce). Basicamente ele funciona da seguinte maneira:

- Cliente requisita um *nonce* (algo randômico, um lixo qualquer) do servidor. O servidor envia em texto puro;
- O cliente também gera um *nonce* qualquer, concatena com a senha e o *nonce* do servidor, gera um *hash* disso tudo e envia para o servidor, junto com o seu *nonce* em texto puro.
- O servidor conhece seu *nonce* e o do cliente, e assim consegue descriptografar a senha.

De uma maneira similiar pode-se usar [Timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_timestamping) para conseguir o mesmo objetivo dos *nonces*.

Como você mencionou desempenho o método acima, o servidor poderia apenas verificar o *nonce* do cliente e verificar se já foi usado antes ou não, mas para isso ele teria que guardar os *nonces* já usados em uma tabela. Mas evitaria do server ter que descriptografar a senha novamente.

**Obs.:** Com o método acima apenas para passar a ideia de como fazer o hash do lado cliente, porém ele requer que o servidor já tenha acesso às senhas.

[Nessa resposta](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/23285) o autor fala sobre a performance do lado cliente. Resumidamente ele diz que se, por exemplo, fosse feito o *hash* em javascript, talvez fosse tão lento quanto o servidor, pois javascript não tem suporte a esse tipo de processamento, tornando-a uma linguagem lenta para este objetivo.

Referências:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3716003/4178863
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1380199/4178863
- https://glynrob.com/javascript/client-side-hashing-and-encryption/

Comment: "O servidor conhece seu nonce e o do cliente, e assim consegue descriptografar a senha" Como, se pra isso ele precisaria da senha original do usuário? (pra refazer o hash) Embora a primeira resposta linkada esteja aceita e bem votada, ela está respondendo a uma pergunta diferente - como dar segurança ao **transporte** da senha - e, para ser válida/viável, assume que o servidor armazena as senhas em texto plano ou similar. O propósito do terceiro link também é outro, aliás ele mesmo diz: "You should still hash the password again on the server side before saving it anywhere in a database".

Comment: Isso. Coloquei os links apenas como referência ao algoritmo do nonce, como uma forma de criar o hash do lado cliente.